# Use raw strings in ClickHouse

Tags: regex, clickhouse, rawstring

I'm using regex to make some searches on strings with ClickHouse and as the docs say [here](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-search-functions/#matchhaystack-pattern)

> Note that the backslash symbol () is used for escaping in the regular expression. The same symbol is used for escaping in string literals. So in order to escape the symbol in a regular expression, you must write two backslashes () in a string literal.

Is it a way to tell ClickHouse to parse a string like a raw string, so that I don't have to use double backslashes in all patterns? Something like doing `r'...'` in Python?

Answer (score 0):

No way.

> Something like doing r'...' in Python

Then how you encode this 'xxx'yyy' ?

You can encode strings

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/encoding-functions/#unhexstr

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/string-functions/#base64decode

Or you can use RowBinary format.